# ViewController does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I ran into a problem recently.

[image]

I'll post some code too. Tried the methods from internet but without success. Also, I have linked the 2 tables to the View Controller.

[image]

Here is some code.

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var carImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pieseDorite: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pieseDisponibile: UITableView!


    var fullNameArr : [String] = [] // i populate the string in a action button, no problem with the arrays
    var fullNameArrDorit : [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        carImageView.image = UIImage(named: ("simplu"))
        carImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

        pieseDisponibile.delegate = self
        pieseDisponibile.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(pieseDisponibile)

        pieseDorite.delegate = self
        pieseDorite.dataSource = self
        self.view.addSubview(pieseDorite)
    }


    func tableView(pieseDisponibile: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
              return fullNameArr.count
    }

    func tableView(pieseDisponibile: UITableView, pieseDorite: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = String(fullNameArr[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView2(pieseDorite: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        return fullNameArrDorit.count
    }

    func tableView2(pieseDorite: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell2:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell2")
        cell2.textLabel!.text = String(fullNameArrDorit[indexPath.row])
        return cell2
    }

}
```

Also, tried to add all other functions, the problem persisted. I think I have linked something bad, I don't know.

Comment: replace all tableview2 to tableview , You can identify the tableview through Tag in same data-source and delegate methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all `tableView2` with `tableView` please, and leave only 1 each method. You need have same delegate methods for all `UITableView` instances. You can separate different instances inside this methods by comparing first parameter with your `UITableView` property. Also add number of section method:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    carImageView.image = UIImage(named: "simplu")
    carImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    pieseDisponibile.delegate = self
    pieseDisponibile.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(pieseDisponibile)

    pieseDorite.delegate = self
    pieseDorite.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(pieseDorite)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {return 1}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if tableView == pieseDisponibile {return fullNameArr.count}
    return fullNameArrDorit.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView == pieseDisponibile {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(fullNameArr[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    let cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell2")
    cell2.textLabel?.text = String(fullNameArrDorit[indexPath.row])
    return cell2
}
```

Comment: Tried that myself before but it didn't worked, that's why i went for tableView and tableView2 functions. Dunno what I did wrong but apparently your code worked perfectly on my project and solved my project.